# UITextView Text Cut Off issue

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am facing some issues with a UITextView.
Basically it's an expandable textview so when you type, it will expand according to the text.
The issue is, somehow my text is gone when I enter return in it.

Here is the screen shot

First image is okay.
[image: This is working fine]

This is how it looks when I press return on the keyboard
[image]

**Here is the code to calculate the height**

```
 // I have created a sub class of UITextView where I have added a placeholder label and bottom line as imageview  

-(CGFloat)getHeight{

CGSize sizeRequired = [self sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 10000)];

return floor(sizeRequired.height);
}
```

[Here is the link of code that i was using for this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mwr84wax1v5eea8/TableViewExapndableDemo.zip?dl=0)

Comment: What's the implementation of auto-expanding? Without the code it's hard to say

Comment: please check out my edits

Comment: Can you tell us or show us where and how u added the UILabel coz i think some ui component is getting placed when you press enter.

Comment: Here is the link of code that I am using : https://www.dropbox.com/s/mwr84wax1v5eea8/TableViewExapndableDemo.zip?dl=0